# I want to call the next page of the plotter.However, the variables required for the next page are also information on the next page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

That's the title. My code requires a YouTube ID to go to the previous page, a favorite variable, a previous page button to go to the previous page, and a next page button to go to the next page, as shown in the code below.

```
                  LearnLevelButton(
                      color: favoriteButton_0_01_01 ? Colors.orange : Color(0xff7ba6f9),
                      text: '1-1',
                      onTap: () async {
                        await Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Video(
                            YoutubeID: 'asfasdf23',
                            favorite: favoriteButton_0_01_01,
                            nextpage: Video(YoutubeID: '', nextpage: null,),
                            backpage:
                            favorite2: '_favoriteButton_0_01_01', text1: '', back: '',
                        ),));
                      }
                  ),
```

You may think you can create and use files for each page, but you used this method because you have to create hundreds of pages.

However, I quickly realized that my method was wrong.
If performed in the following manner, the next page information on the next page and the next page information on the next page are...In this way, the call code does not end because it requires endless information.

```
                        await Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Video(
                            YoutubeID: 'asfasdf23',
                            favorite: favoriteButton_0_01_01,
                            nextpage: Video(YoutubeID: '', nextpage: null,...........),
                            backpage:
                            favorite2: '_favoriteButton_0_01_01', text1: '', back: '',
                        ),));
```

Is there no other way?

The functions provided per page go to the next page, go to the previous question page, and return to the menu, YouTube ID, and favorite variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you implemented this. Please try the following.
Create a class

```
   class VideoClass{
   String youtubeID;
   bool fav;
   int currentIndex;
   VideoClass({this.youtubeID, this.fav, this.currentIndex});
   }
```

Now create a list of this class like `List<VideoClass> allVideoInfo = [];`

Add info as required. `allVideoInfo.add(new VideoClass(youtubeID:.....);`

Now load a page with just index. And inside the page call the url like the following
`allVideoInfo[widget.index].youtubeID` If the user clicks on the fav button then change the value like `allVideoInfo[widget.index].fav =! allVideoInfo[widget.index].fav;`. Convert this list to a string using json.encode and save it in shared preferences. When you open the app for the first time. Use json.decode to get the value from shared prefs and use it.

When the user clicks on the next page. Get the current index and add 1 to it and pass it to the next page. Previous page like current index -1. That will be the best method to handle everything locally.

Comment: Do you mean to create an ID and favorite class with a list in another file?
But how do you implement a button that moves on or returns to the previous one? I was going to use a navigation system.

Comment: And favorite is a variable....bool variable, which is stored locally. How can I save this in the list?

Comment: How do you retrieve the youtube id please?

Comment: Since YouTube IDs are strings, I plan to add them one by one to the list.

Comment: Okay and favourite is again a list of bool saved as a string? Then you can definitely create a list of a custom class.

Comment: Favorites are variables that are stored locally....how can I save them?

Comment: Can you show me how you are saving the fav please?

Comment: Saving your favorites is a bit complicated!


1. In the file with the above code, declare the favorite variable as favorite[0~~~...]. And pass the variable to the learning page

2. When the button is pressed inside the learning page, it is saved as shared_preferences in the Favorites variable.

3. Again, in the file with the above code, save the variable saved in shared_preferences in favorite[0~~~...] through void load().

Comment: just updated by answer.. Please check

Comment: List<VideoClass> allVideoInfo = []; I don't quite understand this part.
But the answer is appreciated. I'll give it a try in a little while. thank you.

Comment: If you have 10 different YouTube video pages. So it's like you create a list of these videos. Just like how you can make a list of strings or int. You can also make a list of custom class..